# Switching to Meteor

Tags: html, css, meteor

I currently have a website and decided to switch over to using meteor. I created a meteor project and I copied all my previous files into this new meteor folder but I get the followings error for each html page.

```
index.html:1: bad formatting in HTML template
```

I am new to meteor, am I missing something? Do I have to do anything for my old files to work in Meteor ?

Comment: did you use a <!DOCTYPE html> tag in all your HTML files? kill that tag and try again.

Comment: Yeah I did but I removed them in all the files.

Comment: did you tried to remove <html> tags?

Comment: Thanks! I removed the html tags and it worked... I'm a bit confused. How can I upload my website to my server without all these tags?

Comment: probably the easiest would to get an HTML parser in your favorite programming or scripting language, load the files one by one, and only print out the head and body tags (incl. content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just had HTML files and dropped them into a meteor install, the result is quite a bit different than what you might expect, by the sounds of it. I'll explain briefly, but my suggestion would be to do the tutorial on the meteor.com website and read through some of the documentation.

The way Meteor works is with templates, which are mostly like HTML, for example:

```
<body>
    {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
    <h1>This is a title</h1>
    {{> text}}
</template>
<template name="text">
    <p>Some example text</p>
</template>
```

To actually have different pages, you'll need to set up a router, which means installing a routing plugin (like iron router or flow router), and then dynamically displaying different templates depending on the URL (which is pretty much what a router does). Routing would be set up in a .js file (as would any other dynamic functionality).

Meteor is great for creating web & mobile apps, but if you just need basic web pages, you're probably doing some serious overkill going with Meteor. I guess if you want to learn Meteor, it could be a good way. Best of luck!

Comment: So can I add all my old pages by placing them into templates? Also would it be good for a website to sell items? I was thinking of using it to update my website by adding java script functions later on.

Comment: @SourceCode Not exactly... You would create a separate template for the header, footer, main content, and sidebar, etc... anything that has a similar layout. You would have one template for the product layout and store product info in the database, and then return product info to the template depending on what route/url you are on. There's a good tutorial on routing here: http://themeteorchef.com/snippets/client-side-routing-with-flow-router/
There is also an ecommerce package that may give you a head start: https://atmospherejs.com/reactioncommerce/core